# Cross Domain Access Include files remote Server

Tags: php, ajax, cross-domain

I am doing an ajax request from another domain, but getting error to access variables declared inside include files...

I put this rule inside my .Htaccess (remote server)

```
Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://originalsite.com.br"
```

And I could do my ajax requests normally, but I could not access the data inside include pages, example:

FILEAJAX.PHP

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://www.remoteserver.com.br/file1",
method: "POST",
data: {
funcao: 'CarregaArtigo',
id_artigo: $('#atualizar').data('id')
},
dataType: 'JSON',
success: function(data) {
});
```

FILE1.PHP (REMOTE SERVER)

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/configuracao/php/funcoes/universal.php';
echo $_POST['funcao'].'</br>';

function CarregaArtigo(){

echo 'Success';

}
```

UNIVERSAL.PHP (REMOTE SERVER)

```
if(isset($_POST['funcao'])) {
    print $_POST['funcao']();
}
```

My actual output:

```
CarregaArtigo
```

My desire output:

```
CarregaArtigo
Success
```

What I must to do to be able to access the content of include files from remote server?

Comment: The expected output should be : Success + CarregaArtigo. In this sequence. print isn't quite right either, because the function doesn't have a return value. My only idea is to check the remote server's PHP error log to see if there are any errors.

Comment: The point is, The include file "universal.php" are not beeing accessed, I am having trouble to access the connect.php too (do the conexion with MySQL)... But this only happens when I do the POST from another domain

Comment: You should log debug information (write it to a file) to find the cause. As an example, does $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] always exist or do other rights exist?

Comment: The log is empty for two servers, its not generating any error, the request returns a 200 code, but I can't access the variables inside the include file ;(

Comment: OK I did it, finally is working hehe, thanks for your time ;)

Comment: You can answer your own question as a record of how to fix it, thanks!